# Windows 7 doesn't detect second monitor after upgrade

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I've just upgraded an old computer from XP to windows 7. It runs a dual-monitor setup, which was all fine under XP.

I have an onboard Geforce 8300 and an ati radeon 7000. Only one of them seems to be active at any one time. I can switch which one is active in the BIOS (I can't remember what option it was, but possible values were PCI/PCI-E/Onboard), and windows can see that 2 graphics cards are there, but will only let me use one, with the remaining monitor staying on stand-by.

All drivers are up-to-date, and my googling is coming up with very little of note. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What is the option's current value? Have you tried to reset your settings to their default value? Have you made sure you have the current BIOS revision? What version of the drivers do you have installed and for which card. In an ideal world you would, uninstall the Geforce 8300 ( from the device manager ), since it basically worthless for any major grapahical unit computing.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Radeon 7000 have multiple video ports? If so you should be able to use more than one output at a time on that video card.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb you can't do this, especially on older machines.  On the newer  Intel machines, Sandy Bridge and newer, some people have had luck getting both to work.

The IGP([integrated graphics processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Integrated_graphics_solutions)) and the external video card both use the same bus lanes, thus they cannot both be active at the same time.  There are exceptions to this though, AGP used a dedicated channel so many users were able to run both and IGP and AGP cards but I never tried this so I can't confirm it.

Many newer Intel systems support FDI([Flexible Display Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_Display_Interface)) which creates a path for the IGP and the external video card to communicate with each other and system.

Your best bet would be to try and use an AGP card(if hardware permits), other than that this is most likely not possible.